# Add Google Apps Email to My Google Account Email Addresses

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, google-account

I have an account ABC@gmail.com and just migrated my domain XYZ.com to Google Apps. I setup Gmail for my domain so now I have two different inboxes: (1) ABC@gmail.com, (2) me@XYZ.com .

Now I want to add me@XYZ.com to my email addresses for ABC@gmail.com, which are listed in https://www.google.com/settings/account ("Email addresses and usernames" > "Email addresses"')

I clicked "edit" and am redirected to https://accounts.google.com/b/0/EditUserInfo . However, after I enter me@XYZ.com to the "Add a new alternate address" text field and click "Save", it alerts saying "me@XYZ.com" is already associated with another Google Account.

I want to use me@XYZ.com for my Google Groups and some of the other serivces instead of ABC@gmail.com . Any idea about how can I add me@XYZ.com to email addresses owned by ABC@gmail.com (so that I can switch emails without applying for access permissions again) ?

(I already have two other email addresses connected with ABC@gmail.com and they work just fine. I only have to confirm the connection by clicking a link sent to my other two email inboxes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue after migrating from Gmail to Google Apps and there isn't a way to use the old Gmail address with your new GA address.

You can however using the multiple sign-in feature of Google Accounts to stay signed in to both accounts always and switch based on the service that you are on.

Comment: Well, for Google Groups, when I click "My membership", I can select "Use [SOME_EMAIL_ADDRESS] for this group ...". Without actually connect the two emails, I cannot use my new email for posting in the group.